# `web3.currentProvider` is undefined with MetaMask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am trying to develop a simple UI for my contract using `web3.js` but I'm falling down relatively early: `web3` (and `window.web3`) is defined but the `currentProvider` property is not.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

function init() {
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('Web3 found');
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
  } else {
     console.error('web3 was undefined');
  }
}
```

The code I am attempting to use is provided above and contains no additional libraries or dependencies (such as `ethjs`). The `init` function is called with the `window.onload` event.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does MetaMask inject Web3?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27137/how-does-metamask-inject-web3)

Comment: try waiting a little longer using e.g. `setTimeout`

Comment: this is just how normal javascript variable declaration works. The idea is to check first to see if there is web3 instance already declared in the global context (on the window object), if so, grab the provider from it and reset it on a newly created Web3 instance. This way you can control which version of web3 you want to use in your code while retaining the provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `var web3 = new Web3();` overwrites the web3 provider that is injected by MetaMask. Therefore, `web3` is defined, but `currentProvider` not. If you exchange this line by

```
var web3;
```

your code from above will work.

Answer (score 1):

A suggested approach for web3 1.0.0 beta is:

```js
if ((typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined')
    || (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined')) {
        return new Web3(window['ethereum'] || window.web3.currentProvider)
    } else {
        // here you could use a different provider, maybe use an infura account, or maybe let the user know that they need to install metamask in order to continue
        return new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/..."))
}
```

`https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/Advanced_Concepts/Provider_API`